# In angular material table , on a button click it should filter data which are older than 3 months

Tags: html, css, angular, visual-studio, karma-jasmine

I had angular material table which contain a column that shows data using this I need to filter data which are older than 3 months

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.